# How I see the result of a function in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have PHP code like these:

```
$q = $conn->prepare("select * from worker");
$q->execute();

$result = $q->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($result);
```

How I can see the json result of the $result variable in PhpStorm?

BTW, I know how to add break point and stop at the line I want I just don't know how to read the value returned from `json_encode`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open menu -> Run -> Evaluate Expression (or press <kbd>Alt-F8</kbd>) and add `json_encode($result)` as the expression to be evaluated.

Or add the expression into the Watches window using the green plus button visible in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a watch like that

```
json_encode($result);
```